# Hiding the status bar on a single ViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to have the status bar hidden in just one scene in the Storyboard?

For example:

I want it hidden in "ViewController A", but when moving via a `segue` to "ViewController B" (eg, a `Navigation Controller`) the status bar will be shown.

I gather you can disable it throughout the app, but how do you do it for just one `ViewController`?

---

The suggestion from   below does work, however when switching to the `Navigation Controller` it seems to cause the nav bar to be drawn in the wrong location.

[image: nav bar bug]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: where does it go buggy? When you switch from the one without the status bar to the one with?

Comment: Use `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` if you want some smooth animation.

Comment: can you try to change `viewDidDisappear:` into `viewWillDisappear:`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Sorry for the delay in replying. `viewWillDisappear:` sorted it, thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

Just put the code on your ViewController.m (in iOS7, Xcode 5)

`- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}`

Answer (score 0):

My solution: In the storyboard, select your Scene and set Status Bar: None in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: This just hides it in the storyboard, but shows when I run the app.

Comment: @zaheer What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: @zaheer Perhaps this only applied to 6.1 and previous versions.. so maybe this won't work anymore. I would go with the other answer and verify that that one works.

Comment: @itslittlejohn That is only a simulated metric and will be ignored at runtime. It is only a visual aid for when you are working with the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```